# 2 Variables in a Python 'all' Function

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to use a python 'all' function to evaluate a set of conditions.  I want to use 2 different for loops in the function but I am not sure if this can be done.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
Box = all([counter != puzzleBoard[x][y] for x in range(9) and y in range(9)])
```

I want to check if a variable `counter` is equal to any of the spaces on my 9x9 board.  I have tried a few variation of for loops and and statements but haven't found anything that works yet.

Comment: change `and` to `for`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your list-comprehension has a syntax error, change the `and` to `for` to create a nested for loop like so

```
Box = all([counter != puzzleBoard[x][y] for x in range(9) for y in range(9)])
```

Also note that you can use a generator function instead of list comprehension too

```
Box = all(counter != puzzleBoard[x][y] for x in range(9) for y in range(9))
```

Comment: I'd also add @tdammon that if your board is only 9x9 then you could write this as `box = any(counter == cell for row in puzzleBoard for cell in row)` or similar...

Comment: @Devesh have a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-on